# MySQL Azure database with username/password

Tags: azure, azure-mysql-database

We are wanting to use the Azure REST API to create Mysql database server instances as listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/?view=rest-mysql-singleserver-2017-12-01#flexible-server-rest-operations and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/flexibleserver/databases/create-or-update?view=rest-mysql-flexibleserver-2023-06-30&tabs=HTTP.

The question is, how do you create users and passwords for the database server you've just created?? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/how-to-create-users "You provided a server admin username and password when creating your Azure Database for MySQL server" [aka in the panel] but we need to automate the process so we can setup database instances with corresponding connection details. Unless I am missing the obvious, a REST API without this wouldn't be much help!?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/flexibleserver/databases?view=rest-mysql-flexibleserver-2023-06-30#operations), there is no REST API operation for creating a user in a MySQL Azure database. Instead, you can use the Azure CLI to create a user for the database. Follow the procedure below to create a user for the database with a password:

First, connect to the database with the admin user in Azure CLI using the command below:

```
mysql -h <serverName>.mysql.database.azure.com -u <adminuser> -p
```

Next, create a user with the following command:

```
CREATE USER '<userName>'@'<Host>/<IP>' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then, grant privileges to the database using this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO '<userName>'@'<Host>/<IP>' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

[image]

Now, you will be able to connect to the database with the above user and password, as shown below:

[image]

You can use these database instances and corresponding connection details to automate the process. For more information you can refer [this](https://www.strongdm.com/blog/mysql-create-user-manage-access-privileges-how-to#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20new%20MySQL%20user%20account&text=mysql%3E%20CREATE%20USER%20%27local_user%27%40%27,directly%20from%20any%20other%20machine.).

Comment: Thats very kind but unfortunately I cannot mark it as the answer because it doesn't answer the question. if its physically not possible, thats not your fault! And glad I'm not missing the obvious. But thank you for your answer. I'm looking for a way to automate this fully.